# How to fill up values from sql into a newform.aspx

Tags: web-part, sql-server

I have a list that has fields like, name, position, year of birth. This information is stored in a database (read only).

When a user opens list's form (an OOTB form) , I want to go to the database,  get the information and fill the fields. My workaround is to make a webpart that will get the information and then add javascript code like:

```
< script >
 var name = "myname";
 var postion = "thatposition"
< /script>
```

Then, a jquery will get these values, fill up the textboxes and make them readonly.

I wonder if there's another way. Javaqscript that talks to the sql server directly is not feasible.

Comment: Can you use InfoPath?

Comment: I prefer NOT to use Infopath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exposing the data sources directly through JavaScript is not recommended. You can customize the form using InfoPath or a Visual Webpart and replace the new item form with the visual webpart.